# How can I open a zip file from an android activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open a zip file from my aplication, but it doesn't works

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///mtn/sdcard/download/teste.zip");
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(it);`

I've already tried other options like:

```
File file = new File("mnt/sdcard/download/teste.zip");
            Intent it = new Intent();
            it.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            it.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/zip");
                startActivity(it);
```

But it doesn't works either.

[EDITED]

If I've winzip app already installed in phone, my app calls winzip app and open the archive, but what I actually need is to open it in my native application

Comment: "it doesn't works" is a useless description of your symptoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ZipFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) if you want to read from a zip file. Android API has its own quite good support for ZIP format.

```
ZipFile z = new ZipFile("/mtn/sdcard/download/teste.zip");
```